# Why do my simulator crash when I change inside my level.txts?

Tags: swift, xcode

> I'm making a word catch app, simulator works fine until I change
>   inside a level.txt file.
>
> When I change an answer or just a clue the simulator crashed
>   immediately.

```
if let levelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(level)", withExtension: "txt") {
        if let levelContents = try? String(contentsOf: levelFileURL) {
            var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            lines.shuffle()

            for (index, line) in lines.enumerated() {
                let parts = line.components(separatedBy: ": ")
                let answer = parts[0]
                let clue = parts[1]

                clueString += "\(index + 1). \(clue)\n"

                let solutionWord = answer.replacingOccurrences(of: "|", with: "")
                solutionsString += "\(solutionWord.count) letters\n"
                solutions.append(solutionWord)

                let bits = answer.components(separatedBy: "|")
                letterBits += bits
            }
        }
    }
```

> When I changed I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of
>   range and in chat log ''MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this
>   platform.''

Comment: You would need to step through the code,  the error is saying that your accessing an invalid index in an array so check these lines carefully. `let answer = parts[0]`, `let clue = parts[1]`

Comment: @Scriptable I checked through the code and it works perfectly. I think it must be something wrong with my level.txt. Because when I just change a letter inside there, the simulator crashed and I get an error.